# Mail merge, send as an Alias

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-script

I was working with a Google spreadsheet with a script associated with it to do mail merge via Google Apps for Education. The spreadsheet works fine, although my user wanted to be able to send from her email account as her alias.

```
    GmailApp.sendEmail(person[1], emailSubject, emailMsg, advancedArgs);
    mySheet.getRange(i+1,3).setValue("OK");
```

This is the line of code that seems to trigger the send. Is there a simple way to slip in a "variable" or something that tells the mail software to send as the user's alias? (I’d admit I’m not very familiar with the semantics of scripting, so please excuse if I’ve used words like code, or variable slightly wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the alias in the advancedArgs as shown here:

```
var alias = "email@example.com";
GmailApp.sendEmail(person[1], emailSubject, emailMsg, {from: alias});
```